# Difference between html4 and html5 tag doctype tag?

Tags: html

Difference between html4 and html5 tag doctype tag?

Comment: What kind of difference? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

The HTML 4 Doctypes describe the root element, and provides two ways (a URL and a code for finding it if you have a local copy) for finding the DTD (so you can expand entities, perform validation and know which tags are optional and which are required for any given element). As a side effect, they trigger standards mode in browsers.

The HTML 5 Doctype is a magic string that triggers standards mode in browsers. It doesn't do anything else because the working group have abandoned the idea of HTML being an application of a generic markup language and require specialized parsers for it.

Answer (score 1):

The difference?

Is that the html5 doctype declaration insanely simple, no more references to dtds, like strict, transitional, etc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Why this was used? The spec says:

> DOCTYPEs from earlier versions of HTML
>   were longer because the HTML language
>   was SGML-based and therefore required
>   a reference to a DTD. With HTML5 this
>   is no longer the case and the DOCTYPE
>   is only needed to enable standards
>   mode for documents written using the
>   HTML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [HTML5 (W3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#doctype)

> 2.2. The DOCTYPE
>
> The HTML syntax of HTML5 requires a
>   DOCTYPE to be specified to ensure that
>   the browser renders the page in
>   standards mode. The DOCTYPE has no
>   other purpose and is therefore
>   optional for XML. Documents with an
>   XML media type are always handled in
>   standards mode. [DOCTYPE]
>
> The DOCTYPE declaration is  and is case-insensitive in the
>   HTML syntax. DOCTYPEs from earlier
>   versions of HTML were longer because
>   the HTML language was SGML-based and
>   therefore required a reference to a
>   DTD. With HTML5 this is no longer the
>   case and the DOCTYPE is only needed to
>   enable standards mode for documents
>   written using the HTML syntax.
>   Browsers already do this for .

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#doctype